# Linking WiringPi library in CMakeLists

Tags: opencv, c++, wiringpi

So, I have a C++ program that I've compiled with `CMake` and uses the `OpenCV` library which I'd like to integrate with `wiringPi` so I can use functions like `digitalWrite()`, `digitalRead()` etc...

Before I tried integrating `wiringPi`, my `CMakeLists.txt` looked like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( Object )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( Object objectTrackingTutorial.cpp )
target_link_libraries( Object ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I was then able to run

```
make
./Object
```

and my program would work 100%!

The `wiringPi` folder I got from running

```
git clone git://git.drogon.net/wiringPi
```

is in `/home/pi`

To integrate `wiringPi` with my C++ program, I've done the following:

1. Modified `CMakeLists.txt` to look like:

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
   project( Object )
   find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
   add_executable( Object objectTrackingTutorial.cpp )
   target_link_libraries( Object ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${wiringPi})
   add_definitions(-std=c++0x -L/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi -lwiringPi )
   ```
2. My C++ program looks like:

   ```
   #include <sstream>
   #include <string>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
   #include <wiringPi.h> 

   /* Functions and variable declarations for image processing */

   int main(int argc, char* argv[])
   {
       /*Testing to see if wiringPi works. Will verify by probing with multimeter.*/
       wiringPiSetupGpio () ;
       pinMode (17, OUTPUT) ;
       digitalWrite(17, LOW);

       while(1){
           digitalWrite(17, HIGH);
           delay(500);
           digitalWrite(17, LOW);
           delay(500);
       }
       /*OpenCV nonsense.*/
       return 0;
   }
   ```

When trying to compile with `make`, I get lots of errors like:

```
 objectTrackingTutorial.cpp:(.text+0x16bc): undefined reference to `wiringPiSetupGpio'
```

I suspect that I'm linking `wiringPi` incorrectly. I'm new to linking multiple libraries together, so if someone could help me out that would be greatly appreciated.

Note that even though `wiringPi` is a C library, I have code that looks like this in `/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi/wiringPi.h`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

which from what I understand wraps the C library and allows for it to be used in C++.

Comment: Did you install WiningPi?

Comment: http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change:

```
target_link_libraries( Object ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${wiringPi})
```

to:

```
target_link_libraries( Object ${OpenCV_LIBS} wiringPi)
```

The last line:

```
add_definitions(-std=c++0x -L/home/pi/wiringPi/wiringPi -lwiringPi )
```

is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's easiest to use the `find_library` function.

```
add_executable(gpioboth gpioboth.c gpiocommon.c)
find_library(wiringPi_LIB wiringPi)
target_link_libraries(gpioboth ${wiringPi_LIB})
```

Answer (score -2):

The only thing I see is in your cpp code when you call the wiringPi functions:

```
wiringPiSetupGpio () ; // space between function name and parentheses
pinMode (17, OUTPUT) ; // space between function name and parentheses
```

If this is exactly how it is in your code the problem can be fixed by removing the space.

To me the error message you are getting then makes sense as it does not include the parentheses in the single quotes.

Comment: Putting a space there is legal C++.  It is not common, but it is legal.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100172/in-c-should-there-be-a-space-between-the-function-name-and-the-brackets